# Logged customer attribute is not saved

Tags: attributes, magento2.2, customer, frontend

I have a native Magento 2.2. I added a static attribute for customer named ficalcode.

On the backoffice, no problem, I can update the attribute. From the frontend it's more complex.

I'm logged with customer #2, on the execute of my controller these line do not modify the fiscalcode :

```
 67     public function execute()
 68     {
 69         try {
 70             //$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());
 71             $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load(2);
 72             $customer
 73                 ->setFiscalcode($this->getRequest()->getPost('fiscalcode'))
 74                 ->setCustomAttribute('fiscalcode', $this->getRequest()->getPost('fiscalcode'))
 75                 ->save();
 76
```

But if I change the id of the customer for 1 and if I'm still logged with customer #2, all is working :

```
 67     public function execute()
 68     {
 69         try {
 70             //$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($this->customerSession->getCustomerId());
 71             $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load(1);
 72             $customer
 73                 ->setFiscalcode($this->getRequest()->getPost('fiscalcode'))
 74                 ->setCustomAttribute('fiscalcode', $this->getRequest()->getPost('fiscalcode'))
 75                 ->save();
 76
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

After there line I do something like :

```
 84             $document = $this->documentFactory->create()
 85                 ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
 86                 ->setExpireDate($this->getRequest()->getPost('expire_date'))
 87                 ->setExtensions(implode(',', $extensions))
 88                 ->save();
```

documentFactory is a model with an after save. On the afterSave it load the customer and save it. The solution is to asociate the customer and not the customerId and make a getCustomer function.

The code become :

```
 84             $document = $this->documentFactory->create()
 85                 ->setCustomer($customer)
 86                 ->setExpireDate($this->getRequest()->getPost('expire_date'))
 87                 ->setExtensions(implode(',', $extensions))
 88                 ->save();
```